# run-time error '713' - Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: sql-server, vb6, runtime-error

Hi I have some software written in VB6.0 that uses an SQL Server, but I get this error:

> Run-time error '713' - Application-defined or object-defined error

Does anyone know what causes this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it related to this?

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;q248055

Might be missing a DLL?

Comment: this link is dead, what was the solution?

Answer (score 4):

This error, according to my own research, is not a vb6 error its actually a crystal reports error, it simply tells u that u need to go back to the developer machine, recreate the setup including all the dependencies and most importantly those for the crystal reports and you will be good to go